# Clear cell content based on another cell for each row

Tags: excel, vba, cell

How to clear a cell based on a change of other cell but for every row separately?
Say, I change AI5 and it clears AQ5, I change AI17 it clears AQ17?

I've got this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("AI5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("AQ5").ClearContents
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

And it works only for the cells in the code.
If I change both to a range of the column, it clears all column AQ, which is not what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Also you could use `Target.Count` in combination with the `Intersect` to avoid errors in case of multiple cell affected.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("AI" & Target.Row)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("AQ" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

You need to tell excel which row, and the row will be the same as the `Target.Row` so you can use that.

Comment: Works brilliantly, thanks a lot!

I do have another favour to ask, though :-)

How the code would look like, say, if clearing of the cell in AQ1 would be affected by a change of any of the cells, say A1, D1, G1 or T1?

And of course, as previously, for each row separately.

Comment: you could use the function `Union()` like this: `Union("A" & Target.Row, "D" & Target.Row, ...)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling with this :-(
If I place Union in place of Range it won't work. When in place of Intersect an error pops up :-(